# How to avoid change theme to dark mode in Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, darkmode

I use `tailwindcss` in my Next.js project. And I don't use dark styles in my components, all components are in light style. But when the OS theme changes to dark mode my website shows as dark.

How to disable dark mode automatically change my project?

Comment: Avoid using the `dark:` variant on classes.

Answer (score 2):

NextJs uses dark mode in itself, so it is configured to work that way.

The thing you can do is to always force light mode by doing something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

And then in header of your page, you can have this small script that will override everything and just use light mode.

```
localStorage.theme = 'light'
```

Ressource: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#supporting-system-preference-and-manual-selection

Comment: I use darkMode: "false" and It's work. Is this a good way?

Comment: Yes if it works you can do that too